# I have a segmentation fault in getc () that is reading from a file

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, hash, segmentation-fault

```
void CalculateWordFrequency(char* inputFile){

    char* word= malloc(sizeof(char)*32);
    char ch;
    int count, letters=0, value;
    FILE *file = fopen (inputFile, "r");

    Hashtable* table = malloc(sizeof(table));
    Init(table);



    if ( file != NULL )
    {
        while((ch=getc(file))!=EOF)
        {
        word[0] = ch;
        word++;
        letters++;
        if(isalpha(ch)!= 0){

            word[0] = 0;
            word - letters;
            letters = 0;
            value = HashKey(word,table);
            Put(word ,value,table);


        }
        printf("%c", ch);

    }
}else{
    perror ( inputFile ); /* why didn't the file open? */

}
```

}

I am trying to get the words from a .txt document and making a hash table with all the words and number of appearances...

my concern is that the getc() is reading an invalid character and gives me a segmentation fault.
some of the text from the file:

Hash table
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
Not to be confused with Hash list or Hash tree.
Hash table
Type    Unordered associative array
Invented    1953
Time complexity
in big O notation
    Average     Worst case
Space   O(n)[1]     O(n)
Search  O(1)    O(n)
Insert  O(1)    O(n)
Delete  O(1)    O(n)
A small phone book as a hash table.

and the error:
Hash table
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000321dc67f3e in getc () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Comment: Most likely, `fopen` has failed and returned `NULL`. I can't help but notice that you aren't checking the return value before passing it to `getc`.

Comment: <code>if ( file != NULL )
   {
  while((ch=getc(file))!=EOF)
  {
   word[0] = ch;
   word++;
   letters++;
   if(isalpha(ch)!= 0){
    
    word[0] = 0;
    word - letters;
    letters = 0;
    value = HashKey(word,table);
    Put(word ,value,table);
    
   
   }
   printf("%c", ch);
   
  }
 }else{
  perror ( inputFile ); /* why didn't the file open? */
 
 }</code>

Comment: Always check what fopen returns.

Comment: `word++` increments the pointer, and eventually points past the allocated 32 bytes. Either use an index (instead of always writing at 0), or reset the pointer periodically.

Comment: I subtract the pointer by the length of the letters read every time; however maybe should free the memory in it??

Comment: `word - letters` does not reset the pointer. `word -= letters;` would.

Comment: the file opening is doing fine I just modified it so everyone could see it, thanks for pointing that out, but It is not the main problem.

Comment: SleuthEye righton!! that was it! THANKS! I failed on fundamentals...

Comment: `ch` should be an `int` in order for `while((ch=getc(file))!=EOF)` to work properly in all cases (for example, when `char` is unsigned).

Comment: well isalpha( int x) returns an int greater than 0 when it is true, and 0 when it is false. just different coding styles :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the line:

```
word++;
```

which keeps incrementing the word pointer, which then never gets reset back to the start of the buffer. So eventually `word` points past the 32 bytes allocated.

I guess you intended to reset the pointer with the line:

```
word - letters;
```

However this statement has no effect. Instead you should use:

```
word -= letters;
```

Other (in my opinion safer) ways to handle this could be to use an index (e.g. `word[letters]`) and keeping `word` constant or to periodically reset the pointer from another constant pointer pointing at the start of the buffer.

Comment: well the reason I'm doing it this way is because the functions were just given to me and they take pointers. but I will take any suggestions! (if they use pointers)

Comment: The other approaches I suggested do not change how you use `HaskKey` and `Put`, just how you handle the local pointer `word`. But whatever works for you.

Comment: MMMM I understand now... Updating only letters and accessing word with it? `word[letters]`